# Dynamic stack data type declaration in c++

Tags: c++, stl, type-declaration

Is it possible to do the following:

```
dtype            //contains data type information  
stack<dtype> st; // stack declartion
```

I want to dynamically decide the type of stack. Is it possible to do this in c++?

Comment: no, it isn't possible.

Comment: You can declare stack with your own struct or class. But what is your question exactly?

Comment: I want to decide the type of stack at runtime not during compilation time. Is it possible?

Comment: stack of `boost::any`?

Comment: If you have a stack of (smart) pointers, you can use polymorphism to change the type of stack elements at run time.  Would that do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. You can use the polimorphism for this reason and keep a pointer to the base class as the argument of the stak's template. Then runtime you can decide what type object to allocate. Important is that it shall be derived from the base class.

```
class Object;
class A : public Object;
class B : public Object;
std::stack<Object*> buf;
if (...)
{
   buf.push(new A);
} else
{
   buf.push(new B);
}
```

Comment: Correct, but I suggest using smart ptrs instead of naked ptrs.

Comment: Yep, for sure, someone needs to care about the dynamic memory )). However my example is only a rough explanation of the idea. Safety and other topics are out of focus so far.